# is it possible to provide alternative fixes in the same branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have two alternative fixes for a bug. Each fix option is a single commit, fixes are based on same parent.
I want to provide those commits for prior review before we decide which to use.
Currently I have option of creating and pushing two remote branches, one for each fix commit.
Is there better / cleaner way, perhaps keeping all fixes in same branch somehow ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two branches *is* the better/cleaner way.

Anything else would be just confusing.

Comment: Thnx, +1 for making me little more confident in my git skills. Seems that I can postpone my fixes till monday, I will probably go with branching and will not forget to accept your answer then, unless someone gives other possible solution. BTW, what could "Anything else" be ?

Comment: Anything else might be applying one fix, reverting it in another commit, and then applying the next fix. Or, if the text doesn't conflict, you could apply both at once, and remove one later. There's definitely no way to push a double-headed branch, or anything like that.